# How to update/ run custom function after add to cart woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I have updated the woocommerce listing/archive page with a custom template to show the product variations in the table row. each variation has its own add to cart button. something similar to this: https://ps.w.org/product-variant-table-for-woocommerce/assets/screenshot-4.png?rev=2485475

I have created a function to show if that variation is in the cart then show the quantity.

```
function product_cart_count( $variation_id ) {
$cat_count = 0;    
// Iterating through each cart item
foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item){

    $product_in_cart = $cart_item['variation_id'];

    if ( $product_in_cart == $product_id ) {
        $cart_count = $cart_item['quantity'];
        return  $cart_count;
        break;
    }
}}
```

On the template page

```
<span class="cart-count"> <?php product_cart_count( $v_id ) ?> </span>
```

This is working fine with ajax add to cart

I want to know how can I run this `product_cart_count()` function after the product is added and update the count.
I have tried `woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments` but it is not working correctly as I need to send product id in parameter.

Comment: You can use woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation. You can read more about it - http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation/

Comment: thanks, Martin, it's working now.

Comment: No problem you may want to check this one too i forgot to mention it woocommerce_update_cart_validation but its not accepting variation_id right away. You may need to loop your cart items. This filter is running when you update quantity on cart page for example